# How to disable framebuffer in initramfs?

Tags: plymouth, initramfs, framebuffer

While using plymouth, I have late splash and tried to fix it, I googled and got lots of suggestions on doing this:

```
vi /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
```

and add:

```
FRAMEBUFFER=y
```

and

```
update-initramfs -u
```

After doing this, I have no splash at all. So I deleted the `FRAMEBUFFER=y` and re-update initramfs, splash came back.

After that I installed something, maybe it's remastersys or n86v or their dependencies, or something else, I have splash gone again and according to the boot.log, I think it's due to framebuffer enabled in initramfs again.

I tried `FRAMEBUFFER=n` in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash` but failed.

Now I have no splash and still can't get it back.

Does anyone know how to disable framebuffer in initramfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it on my own.

I find that when splash doesn't show, I see there's a text on the screen:

"plymouthd could not start boot splash too many levels of symbolic links"

I unzip initrd and look into it, I check lib/plymouth/themes,

**the default.plymouth is a s link which links it self!!!**

I edited it and zip the initrd, reboot, works fine.

Even though there's still something wrong in fb and initramfs, splash came back, I got what I wanted.